# "No such file or directory" or "No such host is known" when running migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I deleted the `migrations` table from a Laravel 5.4 database named `laravel`. When I run `php artisan migrate:install`, I get this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel
    and table_name = migrations)
```

I deleted and recreated the database. I also ran `composer update`. No luck. I can run the command in phpMyAdmin and create the table manually.

This problem sometimes also manifests itself with similar 2002 errors:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel
    and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel
    and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Comment: this works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305502/php-artisan-migrate-with-mamp-and-unix-socket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695450/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you are using `localhost` as your `DATABASE_HOST` in the `.env` file, change it to `127.0.0.1`, then run `php artisan config:clear` and now try `php artisan migrate:install` again.

Comment: Why does `localhost` work in SequelAce but not the `.env`?

Answer (score 19):

Here's what I recommend for `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
```

Then in `Database.php` add folder location:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),
```

Finally, try:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate:install
```

Comment: Thank you!
You are life saver)

Comment: What about XAMP?? Sorry I'm a beginner, ignore if this question is too dumb.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue by setting environment variables in `.env` file:

```sh
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=mysql 
DB_PORT=3306
```

Actually I just changed from `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=mysql`.

Comment: Found this after spending a couple of hours. Works like a charm

Answer (score 6):

If you are using MAMP Pro (not always necessary for the free version of MAMP) then the best thing to do is add this to your `.env` file:

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This assumes your MAMP installation is at `/Applications/MAMP` of course (the default).

*Credit: A comment in this question by @Uncoke*

Answer (score 4):

For mac users, add this to your .env file

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Saved me after looking for a solution for 3 days.

Comment: @mutiemule haha that sucks right.

Answer (score 3):

I am using MAMP on macOS and after editing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and port to `8888` this problem was fixed by adding the following

> 'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),

to `config/database.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases this may happen because mysql server is not running. It happened to me using Laravel 5.7 and restarting mysql server solved it. For ubuntu check the status of mysql server `service mysql status`. You can restart mysql server using command `service mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

Posting a resolution to my own question:

I deleted the folder and recreated the code base, making sure to point my environment to the correct database server. This time it worked. I don't know exactly what had gone missing to cause the original error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that names match in .env and database.php:

```
DB_DATABASE
DB_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD
```

Also change:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
```

to:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
```